# Ng-if wont render ng-repeat on the screen

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am taking a numerical input from user. I'm asking how many number of people do you want? Lets assume the user entered 3.

Each "people" have a firstname and a lastname.

As soon as the user enters the number of "people" it wants and presses submit, I have to make "firsrname" and "lastname" fields for as many people as the user has entered (3 in this example).

This is the code I have written. Look it over and tell me what am I missing?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label for="people">Number of people</label>
    <input type="number" name="people" ng-model="vm.people">
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submitPeople" ng-click="vm.fillPeople()">

<div ng-if="vm.noOfPeopleArray.length != 0" ng-repeat="peopleArray in vm.noOfPeopleArray">
    <input type="text" name="test" ng-model="peopleArray.firstname">
    <input type="text" name="test" ng-model="peopleArray.lastname">
</div>
```

This is how the **controller** looks:

```
vm.noOfPeopleArray = [];

vm.fillPeople = fillPeople;

function fillPeople() {
  fillPeopleArray();
  console.log("This is how big your desired array is.");
  console.log(vm.noOfPeopleArray);
  console.log("End result")
}




function fillPeopleArray() {
  for(var i=0; i<vm.people; i++){
  vm.noOfPeopleArray.push({
  "firstname":'',
  "lastname": ''
  })
}
}
```

It console logs the message and shows me that my array has been populated. But Come what may, it does not render the part after the submit button. And I have tried a couple of variations.

What am I missing here? Please let me out what amateur mistake am I making.

TIA

Comment: You have an extra closing `</div>`

Comment: Is it possible to see entire code? This looks like a snippet of your controller / page

Comment: Why do you are using a submit instead of a button? Why do you even want the `ng-if`? And does it show any inputs after you press the submit?

Comment: Sorry @Weedoze, it was a mistake on my part while copying part of the code and changing names. But, rest be assured that even when I put the divs in place, the code still doesnt render.

Comment: Okay, @taguenizy, I'd put a button instead of a submit and get rid of ng-If and report my changes. Btw, it does not show any <input> after I press submit. That's where it's messing me up. I was just being extra careful while writing the code, thats all

Comment: Hey @Tonino .. i can paste the entire code as it is but I dont really think it's gonna help. Still if you want me to, assuming it'd help you understand better, I'd post it. Let me know

Comment: @SarthakBatra It is necessary to undertand your approach. If you use controlelrAs, if you use angular DOM, etc. Try to make a JSFiddle with it if it is helpful. If you look mine JSFiddle, it works but I assume that you are using $scope

Comment: Ive used `controllerAs` in my config file. The app at this stage is very big and very modular. Each module is an app on its on at this stage, so making a plunk that explains you the structure Ive used is going to be a very big task. @Tonino

Answer (score 0):

Is vm = $scope.vm ?
If not, vm is private and DOM can't access to it. You have to attach vm to scope, like $scope.vm = vm;

Comment: I've done `var vm = this;` in my code. That doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

If I reproduced properly your controller from the snippet that you posted, YOu have to configure your controller to use the $scope like the example below:

```
function fillPeople() {

  fillPeopleArray();
  console.log("This is how big your desired array is.");
  console.log($scope.vm.noOfPeopleArray);
  console.log("End result")
}




function fillPeopleArray() {
  for(var i=0; i<$scope.vm.people; i++){
  $scope.vm.noOfPeopleArray.push({
  "firstname":'',
  "lastname": ''
  })
}
```

open jsfiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/3vzLbro8/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=3vzLbro8

Comment: If he done `var vm = this` in the controller he doesn't

Comment: OP is using `controllerAs` pattern, your answer is totally irrelevant

Comment: @taguenizy "If" he done var. I don't know the rest of the code

Comment: Yes, I am using `controllerAs` pattern in my config file. And frankly, I am more confused after trying to understand your answer. I still dont understand what am I missing.

Comment: @Tonino you also don't know he is using `$scope`